# Populating a Pandas dataframe with data from a list in a unique order of indexes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

so I have webscraped data from an mlb betting site aggregator and have my data points in two lists. The first list is all of the teams. The way it is formatted is that teamlist[1] and teamlist[2] are playing each other, then teamlist[3] and teamlist[4] play each other and so on. Each row index is a team, and each column index is a betting site.

```
     site1|site2|site3|site4|...
team1
team2
team3
team4
...
```

This outlines the general form.

I have figured out the pattern I need to put each betting odd I need to put it into, but I cannot figure out the way to input them properly.

I apologize, I do not have to reputation to post the actual image so I must do a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRfbk.png) instead.This outlines the structure I need to index. The data points are the index I need to go there. As you can see df[0,0] = moneylines[0], and df[0,1]= moneylines[1]. My Primary issue is once I make it through the first two rows (which are done in the same loop) and it tries to go to the third row, it reindexes over the first two rows.[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRfbk.png)

Here is the code I am currently using to populate the DataFrame. moneylines is the list of betting odds I am trying to populate the dataframe with, and teams is the row index:

`ctr = 0

for t in range(0,int(len(teams)/2)):
    for m in range(14):
       df.ix[m,t] = moneylines[ctr]
       df.ix[m,t+1] = moneylines[ctr+1]
       ctr = ctr + 2`

Please let me know if there is anything else I can include to help solve this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is due to your first **for** loop. You increment it one by one so:

first loop :

- t = 0
- you fill line 0 and **line 1**

then

- t = 1
- you fill **line 1** and line 2

and so on...

You should use instead of :

```
for t in range(0,int(len(teams)/2)):
```

this:

```
for t in range(0, len(teams), 2)
```

NB :You can also multiply *t* by 2 in the index but it's not as logic as using the above solution

I hope it helps,

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried this solution thinking it would work, and I was very confident (kind of a doh moment). However values are still being appended in correctly, I even added a print statement to print every loop the current index, and what is being appended to it. The print statements all print the correct index being put in the correct location, but for some reason the dataframe still comes out incorrect.

Comment: Nevermind, I did not realize how much the odds changed every second and that is why the dataframe was not matching up with the live data. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting an alternative to looping over the values of a dataframe, which you can avoid pretty easily here, because doing so loses the efficiency boost of using a dataframe in the first place.

It's not entirely clear to me what the formatting of your starting data is, but if, say, you have a series `s` with values 0 through 195:

```
s = pd.Series(range(196))
```

Then, using `numpy.reshape` you could get the pairings:

```
>>>s.values.reshape((len(s)//2, 2))
array([[  0,   1],
       [  2,   3],
       [  4,   5],
       ..., 
       [190, 191],
       [192, 193],
       [194, 195]])
```

And using it again you could get the desired output:

```
>>>pd.DataFrame(s.values.reshape((len(s)//2, 2)).T.reshape((len(s)//14, 14))).sort_values(0)
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12   13
0     0    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18   20   22   24   26
7     1    3    5    7    9   11   13   15   17   19   21   23   25   27
1    28   30   32   34   36   38   40   42   44   46   48   50   52   54
8    29   31   33   35   37   39   41   43   45   47   49   51   53   55
2    56   58   60   62   64   66   68   70   72   74   76   78   80   82
9    57   59   61   63   65   67   69   71   73   75   77   79   81   83
3    84   86   88   90   92   94   96   98  100  102  104  106  108  110
10   85   87   89   91   93   95   97   99  101  103  105  107  109  111
4   112  114  116  118  120  122  124  126  128  130  132  134  136  138
11  113  115  117  119  121  123  125  127  129  131  133  135  137  139
5   140  142  144  146  148  150  152  154  156  158  160  162  164  166
12  141  143  145  147  149  151  153  155  157  159  161  163  165  167
6   168  170  172  174  176  178  180  182  184  186  188  190  192  194
13  169  171  173  175  177  179  181  183  185  187  189  191  193  195
```